# Trying to benchmark FPS from a live webcam feed using Python timeit and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

So I'm trying to figure out how to properly determine the frames per second that a live webcam feed is capturing at using OpenCV RC3.0 RC1 with Python bindings.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import timeit
import cv2

fps_timer = timeit.Timer('[webcam.read() for x in range(30)]\nwebcam.release()', 'import cv2\nwebcam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)\n')

#time how long it takes to read 30 frames 10 times in a row
fps = (10*30)/fps_timer.timeit(10)
```

Based on other threads I've read on Stackoverflow as well as the OpenCV forums using:

```
webcam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

will not work.

**Question: is this a reasonable/accurate way to determine the FPS of the webcam? If not, what are some better alternatives?**

To give some more details for what I'm trying to achieve:

The reason I want to figure out the FPS of the webcam in this manner is because I'm piping out the results of webcam.read() to ffmpeg via subprocess so I need to know the rough FPS. The core functionality I'm going for is something like (the actual code has a lot of other stuff going on that I don't think is relevant):

```
FFMPEG_BIN = u'C:/FFMPEG/bin/ffmpeg.exe'

#Code to determine the FPS of the webcam would go here

ffmpeg_command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
                  '-f', 'rawvideo',
                  '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
                  '-s', '{}x{}'.format(width,height), # size of one frame
                  '-r', '{}'.format(fps), # frames per second
                  '-i', '-', # The imput comes from a pipe
                  '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
                  '-vcodec', 'libx264',
                   "output_video.avi" ]

video_writer = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=sp.PIPE)

while True:            
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    video_writer.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
```

Comment: It is correct that you can't get the actual fps with `VideoCapture.get`.  The way you're doing it seems okay to me though.  What is the reason for not using openCV's built-in `cv2.VideoWriter()`?

Comment: cv2.VideoWriter() has a 32-bit size limitation (avi files cannot be larger than 4 GB to my understanding) and I'm hoping to record from the webcam over a very long period of time (i.e. > 36 hours)

Comment: I've written 20GB videos with cv2.VideoWriter (on accident, actually), so I'm thinking maybe that is no longer the case.

Comment: Hmm... then it looks like my problem with VideoWriter likely has to do with how I installed opencv. I'm just using the x64 pre-built 'cv2.pyd' for python 2.7. Is that what you are using as well?

Comment: On linux I use `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`.  On windows I install the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ using `pip`

Comment: Hmm... seems like even cv2.VideoWriter() requires a framerate though... see: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: Yes, that is the playback framerate, which is the speed at which the frames in the video are played during playback.  You can define it to be whatever you want, and it has no relationship with how quickly you write the frames to the video.